# Why it is good practice to define custom datatypes in larger projects

Tags: c, gnome

Please help me understand reason of defining C types in some projects.

In my current company I found that someone made definitions of types that are equivalent of those that are already defined in `<stdint.h>`.

Such approach makes harder to integrate 3party code into project, and makes programmer work, bit more frustrating.

But I can also see that some projects, like gnome do the same. There is a gchar, gsize, and gint32 for example.

Because I don't see ANY reason for such approach, I kindly ask for explanation.

What is the reason that `<stdint.h>` isn't sufficient.

Comment: Go back to Windows types UINT, WORD, BYTE etc. There was no certain standard at that time.

Comment: Who says it's good practice?

Comment: Although not mandatory, `typedef` is helpful if you want to make an enumerated type or function pointer type to make your code easier to read/maintain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not good practice. It only leads to less compatibility and portability. I don't see any reason that it should be done. `stdint.h` exists to avoid this.

Comment: But it didn't always.

Answer (score 2):

`<stdint.h>` was standardized in C99. Perhaps the codebase predates `<stdint.h>`, or it needs to compile on platforms that don't have it. It was an extremely common thing to do in C89 and K&R C when there were no portable fixed size typedefs. Even modern projects may keep around these compatibility shims if they still aim to be compilable on decades-old platforms.

> In my current company I found that someone made definitions of types that are equivalent of those that are already defined in `<stdint.h>`.

If your codebase targets C99 or later then there's no need.